# How to select the session table in db2 stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

A stored procedure has a session table, I think it adjusted to verify my statements.

Example:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP
  (
  EMPNO INT,
  SALARY DEC(9,2)
  )
INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMPM (EMP, SALARY) SQL STATEMENTS;

select count(*) from session.temp;
```

I just want to know the result of  `select count(*) from session.temp;`

My mode method:

```
select count(t.*) from (SQL STATEMENTS) t
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To save the returned value of a query (only if it is a one row result) you have to declare a variable like this:

```
DECLARE iCountTemp INTEGER;
```

Then you have to insert the value into said var.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO iCountTemp
FROM session.temp;
```

Hope that helps.